# Text search with aggregation pipeline - MongoDB / PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, full-text-search, aggregation-framework

I am trying to implement text search using aggregation pipelines in MongoDB 3.2
This is how my mongo query looks like:

```
    db.revws.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: { $text: { $search: "terrible" } } },
     { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
     { $project: {score: { $meta: "textScore" },'ProductInfo.ProductID' :1 ,  'Reviews.Title': 1, 'Reviews.Content': 1, 'Reviews.Overall': 1,'Reviews.Author': 1, _id: 0 } } 
   ]
)
```

This is running fine on my collection. The resulting document structure looks like this:

```
{
    "Reviews" : {
        "Title" : "Terrible terrible terrible",
        "Author" : "C. Leinart",
        "Overall" : "1.0",
        "Content" : "I love cameras - i have multiple cameras for multiple uses and this is the absolute worst ever.  The quality of the prints are terrible.  The paper turns sort of a bluish color.  The battery life is terrible and to top it all off, i lost my charger and there is no such thing as a replacement charger in Polaroid-land.  Really...you CANNOT buy a replacement charger.  So if you have one of these, hang on to the charger and be prepared to only use for fun party pics - it's novel but not worth the $$."
    },
    "ProductInfo" : {
        "ProductID" : "B005O08KH6"
    },
    "score" : 2.53571428571429
}
```

When I try to execute similar text search query based on user's input in PHP. I am getting an error "$project specification must be an object".

Here is My PHP code:

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>MongoDB Test - Aggregation pipeline</h3>
<h2>Text search - Amazon reviews</h2>
<br>
<form method="post">
search: <input type="text" name="term"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Display results">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   $term = $_REQUEST['term'];
   // connect to mongodb : default is localhost:27017
   $m = new MongoClient();
   echo "Connection to database successfully"."</br>";
   $db = $m->selectDB('test');
   $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'revws');
/*
db.revws.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: { $text: { $search: "terrible" } } },
     { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
     { $project: {score: { $meta: "textScore" },'ProductInfo.ProductID' :1 ,  'Reviews.Title': 1, 'Reviews.Content': 1, 'Reviews.Overall': 1,'Reviews.Author': 1, _id: 0 } } 
   ]
)
 * 
 */
$pipeline = array (
    array(
      '$match' => array('$text' => array('$search'=> $term))
    ),
    array('$sort' => array("score" => array('$meta' => "textScore"))
    ),
    array('$project' => array( array("score" => array('$meta' => "textScore"), 'ProductInfo.ProductID' => 1, 
        'Reviews.Title' => 1, 'Reviews.Content' => 1 , 'Reviews.Overall' => 1, 'Reviews.Author' => 1, '_id' => 0
                 )
    )
    ) 
);
var_dump($pipeline);
$cursor = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
echo "<br><br>";
echo '<table border="1"><tr><td>text score</td><td>ProductID</td><td>Review Title</td><td>Content</td><td>Author</td><td>Rating</td></tr>';

foreach ($cursor as $doc) {

  echo '<tr>';
      echo
           '<td>'.$doc['score'].'</td>'.
           '<td>'.$doc['ProductInfo']['ProductID'].'</td>'.
           '<td>'.$doc['Reviews']['Title'].'</td>'.
           '<td>'.$doc['Reviews']['Content'].'</td>'.
           '<td>'.$doc['Reviews']['Author'].'</td>'.
           '<td>'.$doc['Reviews']['Overall'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

The output of this php is :

> Connection to database successfully array(3) { [0]=> array(1) {
>   ["$match"]=> array(1) { ["$text"]=> array(1) { ["$search"]=> string(8)
>   "terrible" } } } [1]=> array(1) { ["$sort"]=> array(1) { ["score"]=>
>   array(1) { ["$meta"]=> string(9) "textScore" } } } [2]=> array(1) {
>   ["$project"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["score"]=> array(1) {
>   ["$meta"]=> string(9) "textScore" } ["ProductInfo.ProductID"]=> int(1)
>   ["Reviews.Title"]=> int(1) ["Reviews.Content"]=> int(1)
>   ["Reviews.Overall"]=> int(1) ["Reviews.Author"]=> int(1) ["_id"]=>
>   int(0) } } } }  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoResultException'
>   with message 'localhost:27017: $project specification must be an
>   object' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MongoSearch\MongoSearchAggr.php:49 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MongoSearch\MongoSearchAggr.php(49):
>   MongoCollection->aggregate(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MongoSearch\MongoSearchAggr.php on line 49

I have intentionally put var_dump to display php based mongo query. 
can anyone point out the mistake here? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$pipeline = array (
    array(
      '$match' => array('$text' => array('$search'=> $term))
    ),
    array('$sort' => array("score" => array('$meta' => "textScore"))
    ),
    array('$project' => array("score" => array('$meta' => "textScore"), 'ProductInfo.ProductID' => 1, 
        'Reviews.Title' => 1, 'Reviews.Content' => 1 , 'Reviews.Overall' => 1, 'Reviews.Author' => 1, '_id' => 0

    )
    ) 
);
```

I've just removed one extra array from $project